# Transform CSV files to Java objects using WebSphere Message Broker (WMB)

Tags: java, ibm-mq, messagebroker, broker

I wish to use IBM WebSphere Message Broker (probably V6) to consume some CSV files, perform some validation and then populate some Java objects for consumption by a Java application.  I believe that much of this can be achieved by using the FileInputNode for the consumption of the csv files and the JavaCompute node for the java related stuff.  However, what I would like to know is how can I connect the two?  One way that I see possible is to consume the csv file, then create a message that will be consumed by the Java node.

Any advice would be appreciated.  My familiarity with Message Broker is minimal so please excuse my ignorance.  Incidentally the decision to use WebSphere Message Broker is not mine (corp standards) so although there may be other (simpler) ways to achieve this, I am stuck with using MQ Broker.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Baz

Comment: There's no tag yet for IBM's message broker, possibly due to the name itself. (What would the tag be?  WMB? websphere-message-broker?) So I fixed the product name and changed the VERY generic mq tag to websphere-mq.  Hopefully that will draw some answers.

Comment: Thanks, yes WMB tag and product name now appear more specific to what I am referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up consuming the csv file susing the fileinput node, then transforming them into jms map messages in a javacompute node.  These jms map messages were then consumed by the sink java application.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very generic and it is not clear what you need to achieve. My 1st answer will be very generic too ;-)

Open WMB Toolkit, go to Help - Samples Galery - Technology samples - Message Broker - Message formats - Comma Separated Value (CSV) Message Set. Import this example into your WMB workspace and read 'Read about the sample' - 'Exploring the CSV sample' section as well as other linked pages. Then you can run the example to see what it does and how it fits your scenatio.

Then update your question to be less generic.